# How can I delay deletion of file until after new file is written?

Tags: php

I have a file in a directory that I would like to replace with a current version every hour. I use `shell_exec()` to `zcat` the file and the process of unzipping it and writing it takes about 4 minutes. Prior to this reading and writing, I record the name of the file which is already in the directory so that I can `unlink` it after the new file is done writing. But it doesn't happen in the order I would like it to. PHP executes the deletion while the `shell_exec` is processing. Only after four minutes of an empty directory do I see the newlly written file. Is there any way I can defer this deletion or make it a callback to both reading and writing processes?

```
$log_files = scandir("/cached_logs/");

foreach ($log_files as $key => $val){ 
    //non-secure file to delete 
    if (preg_match("/^access/", $val)){ 
        $log_to_delete= $val; 
    }
}

$ssl_command_string = "zcat log." . $datetime . ".gz";

//execute
$ssl_res = shell_exec($ssl_command_string);

//build the local directory and append the new file name with the current $datetime
$cached_ssl_file_name = "/cached_logs/log." . $datetime . ".txt";

//open the file handle
$new_ssl = fopen($cached_ssl_file_name, 'w') or die("can't open file");

//write
fwrite($new_ssl, $ssl_res);

//close
fclose($new_ssl);

unlink("/cached_logs/" . $log_to_delete); //this is defined properly above, I just didn't post it as it's irrelevant to the problem.
```

Edit:
cleared some things up and corrected syntax errors resulting from scrubbing out information

Comment: Where is `$datetime` coming from? I suspect it may be possible to execute arbitrary commands with this code.

Comment: @Louis I set datetime using `date()` so no it's not really not the issue.

Comment: Strange, I'm pretty sure `shell_exec` is a blocking command. Maybe try  `proc_open` for more control over the external process?

Comment: It might be a lot easier if you did the whole process in an external script (e.g. bash script) and just exec this script from your php code

Comment: @quickshiftin What do you mean by the external process? Can you show me how my statements would look with this `proc_open`. The documentation is a bit over my head.

Comment: `zcat` is an external program from PHP. What I'm saying is `shell_exec` should automatically wait (block) until `zcat` has finished running. I think there's some other strange problem going on. Any chance you're running this script more than once at the same time? Like two people hitting your script from the web at the same time?

Comment: @quickshiftin No, I don't think so. I'm the only person who has access to the script right now. I set it up in a cron scheduler that just calls it like `php cache_log.php` (or something, linux isn't my area) every hour. I monitored the directory at the time the cron was supposed to run. Instantly the files that were currently in the directory were gone and four minutes later their replacements appeared.

Comment: Stupid question, but just to be sure, have you tried running it outside of CRON too?

Comment: @quickshiftin Yes I have. I will do it again and see if the files are immediately deleted as well. Great idea.

Comment: @quickshiftin Yes, the old files are deleted immediately while the script unzips and writes the new file.

Comment: Where is `$log_to_delete` coming from? Also, why is the `unlink` not running against an absolute path, like the line where you create `$cached_ssl_file_name`?

Comment: I just scrubbed out some information and accidentally deleted the leading slash. $log_to_delete is from `$log_files = scandir("/cached_logs/");foreach ($log_files as $key => $val){
    
    //non-secure file to delete
    if (preg_match("/^access/", $val)){
        
        $log_to_delete= $val;
        
    }` I mean it's definitely being deleted, so I don't see a problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like something bizarre is going on. The main reason being AFAIK, `shell_exec` blocks, meaning it will wait until the command it's been given has run to completion before the next PHP statement will run.

I put together a minimal version of the sample script and it works fine for me.

```
<?php
$log_file = './my-access.log.gz';

$ssl_command_string = "zcat $log_file";

//execute
$ssl_res = shell_exec($ssl_command_string);

$cached_ssl_file_name = "./my-access.log.txt";

//open the file handle
$new_ssl = fopen($cached_ssl_file_name, 'w') or die("can't open file");

//write
fwrite($new_ssl, $ssl_res);

//close
fclose($new_ssl);

unlink($log_file);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(is_resource($new_ssl)){
//Handle still open
fclose($new_ssl);
@unlink("cached_logs/" . $log_to_delete); 
}
```

Comment: use @unlink() instead of unlink() to suppress the error if any

Comment: Won't this just fail to delete the old log though? It won't keep trying until $new_sll is a resource will it?

Comment: no it will delete the old log as soon as the resource is availabel.

Comment: unfortunately no, it did not delete anything

Comment: need to use is_resource before fclose